# Boyer-Moore algorithm. Understanding good suffix shift example from course resource

Tags: algorithm, string-matching, boyer-moore

Good suffix example from course resource.

SUSSENUSS

0 !S = 2

1 !SS = 6

2 !USS = 8

3 !NUSS = 5

8 for the rest of them.

My question is: 
Why is !SS = 6 and not = 1, as US after one step matches !SS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

!SS means: 'SS' is a suffix, 'xSS' is not (x != 'U').

- Your text ends with 'xSS' and your pattern with 'USS'

After shifting the pattern right 1:

- Your text ends with 'SSy' (y unknown) and your pattern again with 'USS'

There is no valid value for y that 'SSy' could match 'USS'

If shifting right 6

- Your text ends with 'USSabcde' (a-b unknown) and your pattern with 'USSENUSS'

This may match if 'abcde' == 'ENUSS'